# react-native-device-info crash the app on android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm using [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info) library in react-native. I've used it for about a year without problems, but since the last two weeks the app on Android crashes because of this library.

I get an error as follows:

[image]

They discussed about this issue [here](https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info/issues/438). And they explanation is as follows:

> Unable to merge dex / Multiple dex files / Problems with
>   `com.google.android.gms` react-native-device-info uses
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm to provide
>   [getInstance()][#getinstance]. This can lead to conflicts when
>   building the Android application.
>
> If you're using a different version of
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm in your app, you can define
>   the googlePlayServicesVersion gradle variable in your build.gradle
>   file to tell react-native-device-info what version it should require.
>
> If you're using a different library that conflicts with
>   com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm, you can simply ignore this
>   dependency in your gradle file:
>
> ```
> compile(project(':react-native-device-info')) {
>     exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
> }
> ```

I've tried to add that code to `build.gradle` but nothing happens, the sam problem.

I'm not sure how to solve it. Any idea?

Comment: have you done this ?
react-native link react-native-device-info

Comment: @Pramod Of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `app/build.gradle` dependencies to look like this:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile project(':react-native-device-info')
  compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0') {
      force = true
  }
}
```

If `11.8.0` doesn't work try to replace it with `+`. The `react-native-device-info` uses `+` for it's `com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm` dependency.

**UPDATE**

If that doesn't work, do as suggested in the error message --> try adding `def googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.8.0"` to your `app/build.gradle` to force the version on `react-native-device-info`. (You can change the version as you like)

Then change your dependencies to look like this:

```
dependencies {
  ...
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
}
```

If you take a look at their `build.gradle` file, they handle their dependencies like this:

```
...
def DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION    = "+"     
...
dependencies {
  def googlePlayServicesVersion = project.hasProperty('googlePlayServicesVersion') ? project.googlePlayServicesVersion : DEFAULT_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION

  compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
  compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$googlePlayServicesVersion"
}
```

**UPDATE**

> (This is the solution that worked)

If that doesn't work, try changing your project level `build.gradle` file to look like this (The repositories order is important):

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
    }
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
  }
}
```

The order of the repositories is important because if, for example, `jcenter()` is first, and it will find the `com.google.android.gms` package in there, it will retrieve those sources, and they might be the wrong ones. In your case, the `maven {Google...}` element pointed to the sources you need, and this is why it had to be called before `jcenter()` was used.

Comment: If I use `11.8.0` I get the same error. If I replace it with `+` I get an error `A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'. > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.google.gms.google-services']  > For input string: "+"`

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: If I use `11.8.0` I get an error as follows `> Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0.`. But If I go to `cd ~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services` I see that I do not have `11.8.0` there. The newest is `11.0.4`. But when I try with `11.0.4` I get the same error as in the question.

Comment: Updated my answer... I'm using the `react-native-device-info` lib and everything is working fine for me.. So I'm trying to understand what is done right on my side :) BTW, have you enabled `multidex` ?

Comment: The modifying `build.gradle` did the trick. `multidex` is not enabled. Thanks

Comment: Good :) I'll update my answer and explain why it helped.